# RTC equivalent for 'git pull'

Tags: git, version-control, rtc, rational-team-concert, ibm-rational

What is the equivalent command for accomplishing the use case of a git pull command (**update to the tip and do auto resolve conflicts**) ? I'm looking for the **scm** command which accomplishes the **functionality of a git pull** operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be, as shown in [accept example](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/topic/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/accept_ex.html) a:

```
lscm show status
lscm accept changesetId
```

That is using:

- The [`lscm show status` command](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/show_status.html) to list the incoming change sets,
- The [`lscm accept` command](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/accept.html&scope=null) will integrate a change set from  astream into your repo and local workspace, and make automatic merge (unless there is conflicts or unless you specify `--no-merge`).

Comment: You have another example at https://jazz.net/forum/questions/132555/scm-accept-can-not-detect-the-deleted-directoriesfiles